# remove : '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, passenger

m using Rails and each time I'm generate a command (i.e. rails generate scaffold Article)

I'm having this output at the end of the scaffold:

~/Documents/programming/rails_book/beginning_rails_3/blog3_2_11$ body:text published_at:datetime --skip-migration
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'

I remember this morning I had some issues with [passenger (doc)](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html) by intalling (passenger-install-apache2-module)

```
Create a file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list and insert one of the following lines, depending on your distribution.
```

I d'like to know of to remove this output?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> WARNING:root:could not open file
>   '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'

permissions related problem:

```
sudo chmod go=r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

Comment: can you clarify exactly what `sudo chmod go=r` does under these circumstances?